# Recover locations of moved files

Tags: windows, file-management

I'm desperately looking for a solution to my problem.

A Windows virus moved all my ebooks from their sorted out folders to the parent directory. an example of what I mean is:

**ORIGINAL LOCATIONS**

1. EBOOKS/1/A.pdf
2. EBOOKS/1/2/B.pdf
3. EBOOKS/1/2/C.pdf
4. EBOOKS/1/3/D.pdf
5. EBOOKS/4/E.pdf

**CORRUPTED LOCATIONS**

1. EBOOKS/A.pdf
2. EBOOKS/B.pdf
3. EBOOKS/C.pdf
4. EBOOKS/D.pdf
5. EBOOKS/E.pdf

...with the directories 1, 2, 3 and 4 being empty.

Please note that the files A.pdf..E.pdf are not damaged. They have simply been moved to another directory on the same hard drive.  I have already tried majority of the file recovery programs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible without a backup.

Comment: You are not having luck finding a program that can do what you want because it doesn't exist.  If the files were deleted it would be different.  The files were not changed, so the information on the hdd was not updated, the file system simply indicates they are in a different location.  Move the files back yourself by hand.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows Vista or newer, you may be able to [recover the files with Shadow Copy](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/05/21/using-vista-previous-versions-to-restore-files-you-thought-you-d-lost.aspx).  Otherwise, consider this a reminder about why to [back up early, often, and to multiple locations](http://www.bostoncomputing.net/consultation/databackup/statistics/).